# Kotlin function type mismatch

Tags: kotlin

> I create two function one is sleepExecution and getCustomers I try to
> use sleepExecution  in getCustomer function . I get below compile time
> error

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
((Int) → Unit)!
Found:
KFunction2<CustomerDao, Int, Unit>
```

> CustomerDao.kt

```
package com.main.stockprice.model

import com.main.stockprice.dto.Customer
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import java.util.stream.Collectors
import java.util.stream.IntStream


@Component
class CustomerDao {
    fun sleepExecution(i: Int){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }catch (e:InterruptedException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    fun getCustomer():List<Customer?>?{
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(1,10)
            .peek(CustomerDao::sleepExecution)
            .peek { i : Int -> println("processing count : $i") }
            .mapToObj { i: Int -> Customer(i.toLong(),"customer$i") }
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    }

}
```

> Customer.kt

```
package com.main.stockprice.dto

data class Customer(
    val id: Long = 0,
    val name: String?= null,
)
```

> i get err or exact this point

```
.peek(CustomerDao::sleepExecution)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sleepExecution` is not a static function, but a member function. You cannot get the reference using Class name, instead you have to use the instance variable (`this`). In above case it should be

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1,10)
        .peek(this::sleepExecution)
```

In case the function is in companion object, you can use it as

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1,10)
        .peek(CustomerDao.Companion::sleepExecution)
```

Comment: I believe in the second case `CustomerDao::sleepExecution` would also work, `.Companion` isn't needed. https://pl.kotl.in/Qf6OYqaDY